# Delimiter-Mapped Fontface?

Tags: character-encoding, fonts, postscript

My project is creating a font (or something that I can use somewhat like a font) that maps each *word* to an individual glyph in the font.  The main point of this is to automatically generate "alternate language" passages form arbitrary text, for use in such things as D&D or online games.

I have finished creating an algorithm for generating a new character for a word, in the case that the converter has never encountered that word, but I am stumped by how to store these character descriptions for later use.  Does anybody know of any character mapping algorithms/etc that I could use that can be made to work with PostScript Language Fonts?

The PostScript Language Reference manual did not have any useful information in this regards.  I have tried searching as best I know how for such a thing all over the internet, but all the info my searches have turned has been completely irrelevant.  I am unsure of what this sort of thing would be called, even just a pointer to how to start looking would be greatly appreciated.

If no such thing exists, how would I implement a custom encoding algorithm to do this?  The PostScript Language Reference Manual makes some small reference to that possibility, but my searches in that regard haven't turned up any useful info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think postscript can do this. A postscript font contains two mappings: char-code -> glyph-name, glyph-name -> glyph-drawing-commands. And you can bypass the char map by using the `glyphshow` operator. And you can create a custom font with `definefont`. So I'm imagining something like this (rough-draft, untested):

```
/doglyph {
    {
        cvn glyphshow
    } stopped {
        %<-- Reinstall  font with new word here
        glyphshow
    } if
} def

/myshow { % (string of words)
    ( ) {
        search {
            doglyph
        }{
            doglyph exit
        } ifelse
    } loop
} def
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Note first that the relationship between words in different languages is not 1:1, and ordering also changes. E.g. “amo” means “I love” in Latin, one word instead of two.

PostScript fonts generally have a limit of 256 active glyphs and are static - you can define the font, but after calling makefont you can't easily change them except by making a new font. CID fonts can have many more, and can be rearranged on the fly, although not all PostScript interpreters support that (e.g. I think GhostScript does not, although it does have some basic CID support).

A more usual approach to this is to change the text itself, and e.g. use different scripts via Unicode and OpenType. If you just want the text to look different, though, map some common characters (e.g. "e" in English") to something very thin in some fonts, and wide in others, and map something else to a space, so word lengths appear to change; then you can simply use regular fonts that look different.

Comment: The point is to automatically generate a fictional language sutable for gaming purposes, not actual translation into other languages.

Comment: Also, the problem with that approach, which is why I haven't done it yet, is that I need to be able to add more characters to the set when it encounters words it hasn't seen before.